# Nested class template issue

Tags: c++, templates

Couldn't find an appropriate name for this issue.

I have a template class Array, which contains a nested iterator class

```
class Array<T>::Iterator
```

I want to define a function "sort":

```
template <typename T, class RAIterator>
void sort(RAIterator start, RAIterator end);
```

problem is, g++ can not deduce T from the function's signature. Since I want the function to be independent of specifying T (e.g sort<T>(...) ), I was thinking about this (obviously wrong) syntax:

```
template <typename T, class RAIterator<typename T>>
void sort(RAIterator start, RAIterator end);
```

is there a way to actually let the compiler figure T out?

Comment: Why does `sort` need to know `T`?

Comment: In order to create a heap (for heap sort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a typedef of T inside your iterator class, then you can access this inside your sort function:

```
template <typename T>
class Array{
    class Iterator{
        typedef T value;
    }
}

template <class RAIterator>
void sort(RAIterator start, RAIterator end){

    typename RAIterator::value &v=...;   
}
```

Comment: You should remove `T` from `sort`'s template parameter list.

Comment: Shouldn't it be defined in iterator_traits as in STL iterators?

Comment: @The-Q that is another approach. I find this one more natural. But you can actually have it both ways in this case.

Comment: Where can I find a reference for defining a STL _compliant_ containers/iterators?
Emphasis on compliant and not just STL behavior-like.
I could only find small guide-like articles, not a reference.